# Jasper Report export to xls version 5.6

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Upon running the code it works fine for PDF in the else block ... however **xls** just falls over completely. The stack trace I've tried to figure out the problem, I'm just coming up blank.

```
        Exporter exporter = null;            
        ...
        ...
        ... omitted various: template compile, load, etc, and case statement, to switch to correct exporter

         case "xls":
                exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
                break;

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(baos);

        if (reportType.equals("xls"))
        {
            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jprint));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(baos));
            SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
            configuration.setOnePagePerSheet(false);
            configuration.setDetectCellType(true);
            configuration.setCollapseRowSpan(false);
            configuration.setWhitePageBackground(false);
            configuration.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true);
            exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
        }
        else
        {
            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jprint));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(baos));
        }
        exporter.exportReport();
```

Stack trace as follows when trying to use XLS

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.isForceLineBreakPolicy(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.initReport(JRPdfExporter.java:547)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractExporter.setCurrentExporterInputItem(JRAbstractExporter.java:567)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:735)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:513)
at com.com.com.reporting.ReportManager.generateReport(ReportManager.java:120)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at net.sf.jasperreports.export.CompositeExporterConfigurationFactory$DelegateInvocationHandler.invoke(CompositeExporterConfigurationFactory.java:159)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at net.sf.jasperreports.export.CompositeExporterConfigurationFactory$DelegateInvocationHandler.invoke(CompositeExporterConfigurationFactory.java:159)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.isForceLineBreakPolicy(Unknown Source)
... 17 more
```

The file that is output is just utter nonsense, however, changeing the extension from ".xls" to ".pdf" it is fine as a PDF. Something is drastically wrong, as to what I'm unsure of now.

Comment: Are you using jdk 1.7?

Comment: Yes, the latest version in 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... so it turns out using:

```
Exporter exporter = null;   
exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
```

That doesn't work instead of using the parent class to invoke each of the different report types you have to explicitly use each individual type. I didn't have to change anything else than this

(*obviously for other reports being used that's omitted from my original question*):

```
JRXlsxExporter jrXlsxExporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that ommited code is correct, and you do in fact have instance of JRXlsExporter? I would expect stacktrace like this if JRPdfExporter was provided with SimpleXlsReportConfiguration.

Comment: It is correct the only thing ommited is the switch statement for the various types i.e. `case "csv": exporter = new JRCsvExporter(); break; case "xls": exporter = new JRXlsExporter();break;`   ... and so forth

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I've answered with my approach.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i upgraded the POI so it broke dynamic reports
so the solution was downgrading POI because i could not find proper
version of it compatable with dynamic reports. i had two choices either
downgrade poi or upgrade dynamic report i choose downgrade poi

[image]

[image]

[image]